# How can i convert IQueryable<string> to a string array?

Tags: .net, linq, iqueryable

if I do this...

```
rowNames = _myDB.RowSet.Where(r => (r.RowId >= minId) && (r.RowId <= maxId))
                                                      .Select(r => r.RowName);
```

it returns an IQueryable, how can I put this into: `string[] myStringArray`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
_myDB.RowSet
    .Where(r => (r.RowId >= minId) && (r.RowId <= maxId))
    .Select(r => r.RowName)
    .ToArray();
```

This leverages the [`Enumerable.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension method.

Answer (score 2):

.ToArray()